# Custom activity designer without the Expand/Collapse button visible

Tags: .net, designer, workflow-foundation-4

How can be created an activity designer (in Xaml format) without having the Expand/Collapse button in the right top corner?

I would like to implement an activity designer similar in appearance with the WriteLine activity designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [Collapsible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.workflowviewelement.collapsible.aspx) property to false?

Comment: That's it, with the Collapsible property set to false the Expand/Collapse button it isn't shown by the designer.     Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @axlg: btw, the root activity will never be collapsible, so if you wonder why an activity *isn't* showing the collapse button when it should, that can be the reason...